# Nuget-deployed C# files excluded from Resharper analysis

Tags: c#, nuget, resharper

I'm having trouble understanding a behaviour of Nuget. I've created a basic package that deploys a single Test.cs file into an "HtmlHelpers" folder in a project. I'm following the "convention based working directory" method described on the Nuget site.

[image]

The issue I'm having is Resharper file analysis isn't enabled for this file (the file doesn't compile currently, I've left off a semicolon):

[image]

But, if I rename the file from "Test.cs" to "Test2.cs" then Resharper analyses the file correctly showing the syntax error:

[image]

Has anyone got any idea what's happening here? Is there a list somewhere of Nuget-supplied source files that are then excluded from Resharper analysis? The file properties are the same as for any other C# file, set to Build Action "Compile" etc.

EDIT1

To answer questions from Stephen below, this is Resharper 8, I'm not currently on 9. I've tried closing and re-opening the solution and excluding and re-including the file, neither of which help.

Interestingly, with analysis working correctly on the renamed "Test2.cs", if I then rename it back to "Test.cs" the analysis switches off again :S

EDIT2

Just to add some more info to this, if you Nuget-deploy C# files using the .pp extension, Resharper analysis works correctly on the resulting .cs files. Go figure.

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and back on again? Specifically, does Resharper 'wake up' if you save the solution, close it, and reopen it? Are you on the newest version of Resharper? There appears to have been a bug in a recent version as it wasn't analysing newly added files; updating to latest version fixed it for me. Just possibly this is a related issue...

Comment: @StephenKennedy Thanks for giving this some thought, I've added an Edit section to my question.

Comment: Could you please post this issue on http://youtrack.jetbrains.com for us to take a look at? Thanks.

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk No problem, have created the issue on YouTrack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReSharper excludes source code that has been delivered as part of a NuGet package from analysis - it treats it as third party code that you did not write and do not want to maintain. E.g. it won't show any inspection results for files such as jquery.js or angular.js - you don't own these, don't intend to maintain them as part of your project, and any changes you do make are likely to get overridden the next time you update the project. So, inspections are disabled for these files, but the files are still indexed to allow navigation.

Comment: Great, that makes perfect sense, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else has this issue it only happens if Nuget delivers a .cs file. If you get Nuget to deliver a .cs.pp file, Resharper correctly analyses the resulting .cs file in your solution.

I was new to Nuget when I started this work and it turns out I needed to make them .cs.pp files anyway in order to use the correct project namespace when importing. So the problem has gone away.